# Python Y-axis scale normalization

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have set the y-axis limit using the below line of code.

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 2047, 32))
```

When I plot using the above y-axis range, I am getting ticks at 
0, 32, 64, 96,.....2047 and displaying the same.

But is there any way I can normalize the above dividing by 32 to display 0, 1, 2, 3,...63?

Comment: for that you need to normalize your data (better), whats the max value for the y in the data?

Comment: actually its quite complicated. its a 4-D plot with color being the 4th plot. so i just want to normalize the numbers on axis. is there a way ?

Comment: `plt.yticks(np.arange(0, max_val+1000, 500))` here what i am doing, max_val is the max number of y and 500 is the difference. So it will start from 0, 500, 1000, 1500

Comment: Isn't this same as np.arange(0, 2047, 32) except max_val term which is always constant - 2047 in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want the ticks to be placed at 0, 32, 64, 96, ... but the values (ticklabels) at the ticks to be displayed as 0, 1, 2, 3,...

To do so, first you can set the ticks as you are doing

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 2047, 32))
```

and then set the ticklabels as

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(np.arange(0, 64, 1))
```

Give it a try and let me know in the comments if this is what you want.

Comment: Oh. Did not know it is this simple. Thanks a lot for the quick solution :) Yes. This is what I wanted. I was actually trying out normalization functions.